# UITableView dataSource must return a cell in UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIPopoverController displaying a table view.

I get a crash as per:

> , /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:6509
>   2015-05-06 17:12:05.795 Next[39510:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x037691e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0341e8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x03769048 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
>       3   Foundation                          0x014284de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
>       4   UIKit                               0x025c0d7f __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 426

if I set numberOfRows in section to 0, i see the tableView

If i set the number of rows to 1 i get this crash, so the table is being displayed and will require cells to be displayed.

The *CellForRowAtIndexPath* is **NEVER** called, thus the crash. Why is this?

Delegate and dataSource are set correctly in IB

Its initiated and brought to view as per:

```
TablePickerViewController* picker = [[TablePickerViewController alloc] initWithSelectableOptions:options selectedIndex:selectedIndex selectionBlock:selectionBlock];

self.popover2 = nil;


self.popover2 = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];

self.popover2.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 200);

self.popover2.delegate = self;

picker.popover = self.popover2;

[self.popover2 presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

return picker;
```

For clarification, the frame Passed in to present from is 0,0,1024,768 (Landscape Orientation)

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 1;
```

}

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentt forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentt];
}

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
if (self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
cell.textLabel.attributedText = self.options[indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

Comment: Odd.  If `cellForRowAtIndexPath` wasn't being called, I wouldn't expect an error about it returning nil.

Comment: I know @PhillipMills - number of rows is being called though, the table view is shown on the UI if rows ==0 so it's not that it won't call 'CellForRow' because none to display' I'm stumped! Years of making table views too!

Comment: Random questions: When you say it's never called, you've used a breakpoint or `NSLog()` to verify that?  Do you do anything creative with registering nibs or classes for cells?  Is everything OK with the cell reuse identifier in IB...and with `cellIdentt`?

Comment: @PhillipMills not being creative in creating cells, no subclassing, and yeah NSLog never fires! I have coded more or less exactly same in a separate project and it works perfect, making me think Xcode isn't playing well! I cleaned all derived data and so forth. :-(